# How to display HTML document correctly in UITextView

Tags: html, ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have an UITextview inside a iOS app, where I want to display a HTML document. I found solutions to transform the HTML document to an NSAttributedString.

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                          options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

Now I am struggling with the fact, that the HTML document is not displayed as it should be.

For example I want to display this HTML-example inside my UITextView: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_example_website

It should look like this:
[HTML document in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w44pF.png)

But it looks like this:
[HTML document on iPad emulator inside UITextView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYl5s.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Explanation: NSAttributedString with the appropriate init method you used translated/parse only some tags. It's not a full HTML parser, that's why you should use a `WKWebView` to read really of them if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it better to display it in WKWebView [WKWebKit Offical Documentation](https://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=2202.OmigoS-1j5F5mZs_jHYunWJsYmduYmpna2dhbnJ6bHU.9db2e28fef0e10e3f2e4c0e103224cefcddabea7&uuid=&state=jLT9ScZ_wbo,&&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5Hyx_fyvalFN0qLUHTFd-nWjbJSXTQN19Bsd9y5mC4H0WpprLSzaymQUfy0Vik_fZmE6l1sXcT4qGqJw60BPpbz4TvNLjFfnJf-VJNuFXA5S8LYyD5tXkqRf7j_bXi7WvgDB5NdsD86dzhs8SXhzdmLo5f1xkiIFNY6PNrkNGHJ6kq4tpEGiu2uoo-2P3gHxTGIKVlOgQTuoiLJtNkpMnqZKloeK52ck63cL-X_vjpsAUQswdFQVuq0kZdubc0qaaiK5VGRDdJjy0gatGykXN1xPXLViefbKkTm2JGftF-dMhHNix5xF7C0j3N3I0Ey-9Af5vp6I34fEHguYm8gOTFDMdf7w7iqO_1AweB2kGKlTEGXJ_y1NuXFowB3rHXOrP9KOudRIY_cLUDzfl4dboZfU7DQe2qJjKe6wcqa59gsc0Af7yceMyMvdGyTqy3BTiVpR6FcD0OHC5Eo-hkr7pG_ZsjKNTsFPOT9SNBhMbr1-hKFjP0iglLLL3oWVQGj21bgvWib_Tv3RrJd0iglVsuXHxiq7YccKhz1Lr5tB8N9U6sFBU7Xf62UH3_GcOHEnyRP_Yz04WAihwc3SFkukbbD6eWaZ9T4e9udyy4g6PB-YhYYprE-0P6x-9YNo7hI5ILvQYMiJEQGK_WfYt12XJSY8Np9P8Q7okLh82oXBnTKzFr8G38suzfxaXNtMxbpZqWOH-F3ZKdgL_Gs4zzxxgg&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejY4cHFySjRXSWhXQjZsSUhWODZUN19SSXAyR3J3Z0ZfNDNfelVoWm10Sk5sZDdhZ3FaVlp4czg0UUVCVnVrTmhqanBEb1d1UDVlZjl6MXVud3pzUjdTR3FzRmFCQW1nTXpPYldxLTd1NzBrQkhkWDNWMWJlQ1luZ01HeGt1dXpTU1NyMThGMkpCQnhRLCw,&sign=c14ff0e86d4ef71353069fbce7996665&keyno=0&b64e=2&ref=orjY4mGPRjk5boDnW0uvlrrd71vZw9kpfmwSlf_6ZUYZ2BPbpFQPbiJaDMGeMgqDNe-z_sxku06sQRH0D_TqJA,,&l10n=ru&cts=1627137117141%40%40events%3D%5B%7B%22event%22%3A%22click%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2257wyw01-00%22%2C%22cts%22%3A1627137117141%2C%22fast%22%3A%7B%22organic%22%3A1%7D%2C%22service%22%3A%22web%22%2C%22event-id%22%3A%22krhvfetxv4%22%7D%5D&mc=1&hdtime=2934)

Comment: Ok, thanks for this hint. But is there also a solution for a normal UITextView?

Comment: Just you need to display the content of html page, fully as a webpage. So better use webview.